# How to get tkinter OptionMenu to display the name of the selected option?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu, tkinter.optionmenu

In `tkinter`, I have created an option menu using the `OptionMenu` class. As an example, the `OptionMenu` below has options `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, etc.:

```
self.clicked = tk.StringVar(self.parent)
self.clicked.set("Select Column")

self.drop = tk.OptionMenu(self.parent, self.clicked, 'Select Column', command=self.idle)
    for i in columnNames[:]:
        self.drop['menu'].add_command(label=i, command=tk._setit(self.clicked, i, self.select_data))
self.drop.pack()
```

Note: the function `self.idle` is just a `lambda *args: None`.

The function `self.select_data` is as follows:

```
def select_data(self):
    for col_name in df.columns:
        if col_name == self.clicked.get():
            self.option_display = col_name
```

The function `self.select_data` simply retrieves the option the user selects from the `OptionMenu`, but how would I update the `OptionMenu` to display the option selected in `self.select_data`?

As an example, if the user selects option `A`, how would I update the `OptionMenu` to show `A`as selected?

Comment: In your case, `self.selectData()` should expect a argument which is the selected item.

Comment: What argument exactly? I'm a bit confused...in `self.selectData()`, I'm trying to print out the selected option from the OptionMenu.

Comment: The `selectData` function should be something like that: `def selectData(self, selected)` where `selected` will be the selected item of the `OptionMenu`.  Or you can use `self.clicked.get()` inside the function to get the selected item.

Comment: If I were to do `def selectData(self, selected)`, would the code inside simply be `print(selected.get())` by calling `self.selectData(self.clicked)`. Also, the `self.clicked.get()` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `selectData()` function should have the following signature:

```
def selectData(self, selected):
    print(selected)
    # or print(self.clicked.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

This will print the dropdown selection to the console. but my suggestion is to avoid console in GUI based applications. create a text indicator and print output to it

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
def OptionMenu_SelectionEvent(event):
    print(var.get())
    pass
var = StringVar(); var.set("one")
options = ["one", "two", "three"]
OptionMenu(tk, var, *(options), command = OptionMenu_SelectionEvent).pack()
tk.mainloop()
```